# Video file Uploading

Tags: ee, video

Does anyone know what file format for videos Expression Engine will allow to be uploaded? I tried MP4 and WMV neither one is working via the upload screen

Comment: Please revise your question to detail exactly what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit mimes.php to add the mime type that you need. It is located

> system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php

For a complete list of mime types that you can add to that file go here: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/